# Add up value from multiple objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has multiple objects. Each object has a cost. I'm trying to calculate the total price of all items combined.

```
static calculateCosts(shoppingCart: Array<any>):number {
    let price = null;

    for (let item of shoppingCart) {
        price = item.price
    }

    console.log(price);
    return price;
};
```

Obviously this only show the cost of the the last item in the shoppingCart. What would be a good method to add up the costs of each item?

//edit

After looking a bit more into some basic JS features this looks like a solution:

```
static calculateCosts(shoppingCart: Array<any>):number {
    let price: number = null;

    for (let item of shoppingCart) {
        price += item.price
    }

    return price;
};
```

`+=`

Comment: You may consider tagging this ECMA Script 6 or ES6 or ES2015 as static classes are not yet well supported by most browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a reduce function to do that.

First of, because you know your array will be an array of objects containing a price member, you can type it (I understand you are using TypeScript).

Then, you can use the reduce function of an array to calculate the total.

Here's a solution:

```
static calculateCosts(shoppingCart: Array<{price: number}>):number {
  return shoppingCart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not caught up on all this ES6 stuff and will worry about it when I can actually use it. But it seems like in ES5 JS this should be an easy thing to do.

```js
var array = [
 {
   cost: 1.25  
 },
 {
   cost: 2.5 
 },
 {
   cost: 0.75  
 },
 {
   cost: 1.5  
 }
];

function sum(a){
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    sum += a[i].cost;
  return sum;
}

console.log(sum(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objects = [
   {id: 1, cost: 45},
   {id: 1, cost: 55},
   {id: 1, cost: 65},
   {id: 1, cost: 75}
];

var sum = 0;

objects.forEach(function(obj) {
   sum += obj.cost;
});

document.write(sum);
```